# How to listen requests with mitmproxy and vpn

Tags: android, vpn, mitmproxy

I am trying to listen to mobile app to requests via mitmproxy, but the application that needs to be listened to only works with vpn. Without it, it gives a network error. But if you use vpn, then the requests are obviously not displayed. Maybe someone has encountered this problem?

I tried changing dns in the device settings and via apk apps. I also tried to connect to another network, and use a vpn not on a mobile device, but on a PC that distributed wi-fi

Comment: I don't think that you can use proxy and VPN at the same time. The only chance I see is to use a rooted device and try to capture the traffic inside the app e.g. using frida. But that will require a lot of self-written frida code. Or you try to use Frida to disable the VPN requirement.

Comment: @Robert yes, now im using frida for bypass emulator detection. if you do not turn on the vpn, it says that there is no internet.

Comment: Is it an Always-on-VPN or a per-app-VPN? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/vpn

Comment: @Robert Its android app vpn